# How to return intersecting array in ruby and preserve up/lowercase?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I want to create a function that returns a list of array contained in another list of array. This is what I came up with:

```
def coffee(arr)
  acceptable_coffee = ["dark", "blend", "handsome"]
  good_coffee = acceptable_coffee & arr.map{|n| n.downcase}
end
```

Possible inputs may contain the elements in `acceptable_coffee`.Their case might not always be downcase, i.e.:

```
arr1 = ["dark", "decaf", "java", "HANDSOME"]
arr2 = ["dark", "smooth", "BLEND"]
```

I want the function to return the array that contains acceptable elements while preserving their up/downcase. The function then, should return:

```
coffee(arr1) #=> ["dark", "HANDSOME"]
coffee(arr2) #=> ["dark", "BLEND"]
```

Currently it is returning `["dark", "handsome"]` and `["dark", "blend"]`, respectively. If I don't do downcase, it won't intersect properly. How can I return the intersecting array while preserving the up/downcase? Don't worry about other edge cases. Assume the possible array inputs' elements are either completely uppercased/ completely lowercased, like the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This'll get the intersection, but id doesn't exactly use the funky `&` operator or sets.

```
def coffee(rest)
  acceptable_coffee = ["dark", "blend", "handsome"]
  rest.select { |name| acceptable_coffee.include? name.downcase }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the prettiest way, but you can do this to preserve the upper case.

```
def coffee(arr)
  acceptable_coffee = ["dark", "blend", "handsome"]
  good_coffee = (acceptable_coffee & arr) + (arr & acceptable_coffee.map(&:upcase))
end

coffee(arr1) #=> ["dark", "HANDSOME"]
coffee(arr2) #=> ["dark", "BLEND"]
```

Comment: You method won't work for `coffee(["Dark"])`, assuming it should return `["Dark"]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def coffee(arr, acceptable)
  r = /#{acceptable.join('|')}/i
  arr.select { |s| s =~ r }
end

acceptable = ["dark", "blend", "handsome"]

coffee ["dark", "decaf", "java", "HANDSOME"], acceptable
  #=> ["dark", "HANDSOME"] 
coffee ["dark", "smooth", "BLEND"], acceptable
  #=> ["dark", "BLEND"]
```

Note

```
r = /#{acceptable.join('|')}/i
  #=> /dark|blend|handsome/i
```

Answer (score 0):

I always turn to regular expression when I want to select strings that match a pattern.

```
def coffee(arr)
  acceptable_coffee = /\A(?:dark|blend|handsome)\z/i
  good_coffee = arr.grep(acceptable_coffee)
end

arr1 = ["dark", "decaf", "java", "HANDSOME"]
arr2 = ["dark", "smooth", "BLEND"]

coffee(arr1)  #=> ["dark", "HANDSOME"]
coffee(arr2)  #=> ["dark", "BLEND"]
```

Explain about the regexp `/\A(?:dark|blend|handsome)\z/i`:

`\A` matches the beginning of a string (before the first character).
`(?:)` is a non-capture group, where I can put `|`.
`|` reads "or".
`\z` matches the end of a string (after the last character).
The trailing `i` outside `/.../` means ignore case.